# how username and password sent to the method using Basic authentication

Tags: rest

I  want to know how username and password sent to the method by using Basic authentication in rest in server. I want to go for Basic authentication because of domainname\username.

Is it possible to create custom username and password for basic authentication?

Comment: Please tag your architecture. "sent to method" is very unclear.

Comment: For how to create the header, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side